# Issue Converting String to User Local Time using DateFormatter() Swift 4

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert a string to a Date type. I am trying to convert to users local time, but I am getting a strange output. Here is the function that I am using and the results I am getting. The string input I am using looks like "10:15 AM:

The function below is returning a string, but that is just to look at the output, it will eventually return a Date.

```
func convertTime(date: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    print(Locale.current.identifier)
    print(TimeZone.current.identifier)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    if let formattedTime = dateFormatter.date(from: date) {
        let userFormatter = DateFormatter()
        userFormatter.timeStyle = .short // Set as desired

        return userFormatter.string(from: formattedTime)
    } else {
        return "Unknown date"
    }
}
```

the first part of the output is the input string, and the second part is the converted time. I expected to get the converted time in the America/Denver timezone, but tht is not the case.

```
en_US
America/Denver
Input String: 10:58 AM, Output String: 3:58 AM
en_US
America/Denver
Input String: 7:43 PM, Output String: 12:43 PM
en_US
America/Denver
Input String: 12:14 PM, Output String: 5:14 AM
```

Comment: If you want local time you shouldn't set the time zone to UTC

Comment: You want to convert a string that looks like "10:15 AM" into a date object that will always be the current day at 10:15 AM in the user's local timezone?

Answer (score 0):

Your output is correct for the code you posted. You treat the string "10:58 AM" as UTC time in the year 1. This is because the time string has no date and because you specific set the UTC timezone on the date formatter.

And you get the output of "3:58 AM" in local time (which is Denver for you). Denver is UTC-7 normally (UTC-6 during daylight saving time).

Your code is working correctly if your goal is to convert a UTC time to user's local time (Denver in this case).

If you want to treat the original string as local time and your goal is to just change the format, don't set the `timeZone` on the firs date formatter.

Unrelated but there's no need to use the line:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
```

since the date formatter defaults to the current locale.